# Parsing with XML

Tags: python, list, parsing

Im trying to parse a web blog page and pull out certain data into a list. Here is the xml..

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycle/rss/PLCWeeklyXMLDownload.xml

There are multiple records but from each i need to pull out the Software Title, Version Number, Release Number, ModLevelNumber and End of Service date (if any) and put them into a list

I am running python code but im new to xml,any help is appreciated

```
 def myDownload():
   import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
   import urllib.request
   response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycle/rss/PLCWeeklyXMLDownload.xml")
   tree = et.parse(response)
   root = tree.getroot()
   aList=[]

   for child in root:
      for node in child.findall("SWTitle"):
        title = node.text
        aList.append(title)
      for nodes in child.findall("Versions"):
        for version in nodes.findall("Version"):
          for release in version.findall("Release_Mods"):
            for mod in release.findall("Release_Mod"):
              rNum = mod.find("releaseNumber")
              rNumber = rNum.text
              nNum = mod.find("modLevelNumber")
              nNumber=nNum.text
              aList.append(rNumber)
              aList.append(nNumer)
```

Can anyone help adjust this code because it doesnt seem to work

Comment: What are you having problems with?

Comment: Look for an xml library for python. Then, if you know where the node will be in the xml tree, then you can tell it to look there.

Comment: @Blender can you check my code

Comment: @BAI: What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Blender ]it doesnt create the list i need it 2 im not sure where the error is occuring

Answer (score 1):

Use lxml library to parse the xml. ElementTree doesn't work with more nested tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) library for this:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

r = requests.get('http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycle/rss/PLCWeeklyXMLDownload.xml')
xml = r.content
xml_dom = etree.fromstring(xml)

# Iterate over <SWTitleRecord>
for record_node in xml_dom:
    data = {}
    for attr_node in record_node:
        if attr_node.tag == 'SWTitle'
            data['title'] = attr_node.text
        elif attr_node.tag == 'Versions':
            # parse versions
    ...
```